# Single page web application height issue on Android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, dom

I'm working on an SPA which uses body height:100% and one of the pages contains a form with several fields for entering information. On an Android tablet when you tap on one of these fields the soft keyboard appears, which resizes the window element and subsequently the body element, subtracting the height of the soft keyboard. This results in the page being reduced to less than 300px high, making the form unusable. On iPad the keyboard is overlaid on top of the page, so the window height is unchanged.

I have found a partial fix, which involves setting the body height to equal the window height on page load, and also on orientationchange:

```
$("body").height($(window).height());
window.addEventListener("orientationchange",function(){
   $("body").height($(window).height());
}
```

This fixes the height squishing issue and means that the form can be used, however there is an issue in the instance where the user changes the orientation while the soft-keyboard is open.

The keyboard remains open after the orientation change and the window height (and the body height) is changed to the height minus the keyboard. When the field is blurred and the keyboard disappears, the body remains the reduced height and has a nasty white bar at the bottom.

To illustrate the problem, here's some numbers:

- Landscape - Closed Keyboard: 688px
- Landscape - Open Keyboard: 273px
- Portrait - Closed Keyboard: 1168px
- Portrait - Open Keyboard: 716px

If you switch from Landscape - Open Keyboard to Portrait - Open Keyboard, and then close the keyboard, the body height remains at 716px, putting a white bar along the bottom. I need to somehow work out the height that it SHOULD be with Closed Keyboard, at the point of orientationchange, while the keyboard is still open. Bearing in mind the fact that the device resolution, application chrome and keyboard sizes will vary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the CSS `vh` unit, which is the percentage of the viewport.

E.g. CSS

```
body {
    height: 100vh; /* The body element is always 100% of the viewport's height. */
}
```

You should not need the JS event handler in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem. Because the viewport height changes when the virtual keyboard opens, so the issue with the page being squished and unusable returns.